# Select data from SQLite that contains XML formated parameters

Tags: python, xml, sqlite

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788597/select-data-in-xml-format-using-for-xml). My SQLite database records events on a production machine. I wish to find unsuccessful login attempts. My code works but is there a better solution?

The columns of table `Event` are `Name`, `User`, `Timestamp`, and `Details`. When a user logs in, a new record is created. `Name` column contains login and `Details` column XML data shown below. Successful login will get True, if unsuccessful False. I wish to select all false logins. The code works by using the `Like` keyword but it might not work for other XML data:

```
import os
import sqlite3

def query_db_files(folder_path):
    count=0
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file.endswith(".db"):
            connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(folder_path, file))
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            query = "SELECT Name, User, TimeStamp FROM Event WHERE Name = 'Login' AND Details LIKE '%Success%' AND Details LIKE '%False%'"
            cursor.execute(query)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            if results != []:
                for tuples in results:
                    print(tuples)
                    count=count+1
    print(count)
query_db_files("C:\\Users\\David\\Downloads\\Optel\\Audit Trail")
```

The XML parameterized data looks like this (column that contains it is named `Details`):

```
<Parameter>
    <Name>Type</Name>
    <Value>21CFR11</Value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter>
    <Name>Success</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
</Parameter>
```

Comment: Please explain *xml parameterized data* and how that relates to first code block.

Comment: Also, that is not XML since it is missing the root node. Is data saved exactly like that fragment or did you extract a part from larger XML?